# MVC4 image upload and preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here's my code: css:

I keep on receiving an error message. It shows

> "missing a property name before colon(:)in the "(property)":"(value)"declaration"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong could any one help me with this?

```
body {.thumb { height: 75px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 10px 5px 0 0; } }
```

Comment: What are you trying to style here - elements with `class="thumb"`? -

Comment: It is enough to create class "thumb". Why do you wrap it with the "body"?

Comment: Thank you so much. Got It :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the brackets:

.thumb { height: 75px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 10px 5px 0 0; }

Then apply the class "thumb" on relevant elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. Got it:)